# Where are JSTL <fmt:message> data stored and how can I access it

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Where are JSTL  messages stored and how can I access it without using a JSP tag? The reason is I am trying to get this information from client-side javascript.

The end goal is to be able to access this data from the Java backend and create an API endpoint to expose it to the front-end without relying on JSP compilation.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Messages are stored as either property files or resource bundles. It is best to just load them in your Java code and expose them as REST.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed on client side while JSTL is done on server side. So it is not possible to pass JavaScript variables in `<fmt:message>` tag.

You may have to use Ajax or get all variables needed by client side on server side.